# Why Can't I Turn Off DpiAwareness in Python After Turning It On?

Tags: python, dpi-aware

I use this code to turn on Dpi Awareness, in Python 2.7, under Win10

```
import ctypes
import platform
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
```

but

```
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(False)
```

does not turn it off. I am looking for any suggestions please.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't expect the DPI awareness to change during the running of a program.  The [documentation for `SetProcessDpiAwareness`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness) is sprinkled with warnings, and they suggest you use an application manifest instead.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `SetProcessDpiAwareness`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness) explicitly states:

> Once API awareness is set for an app, any future calls to this API will fail.

What you're asking for simply isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed that part of the docs.

Comment: @jvbSherman I missed it the first time through too.

Answer (score 3):

While Mark Ransom's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68548477/4311651) is technically correct, it's still possible to toggle the DPI awareness state thread-wise via [SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreaddpiawarenesscontext). A minimal example:

```
from ctypes import windll, wintypes
windll.user32.SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(wintypes.HANDLE(-2))  # Toggle ON
windll.user32.SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(wintypes.HANDLE(-1))  # Toggle OFF
```

This function was introduced in [version 1607](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_1607) (July 2016) of Windows 10. More DPI features were introduced later as discussed in [this official blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/).

Here's an implementation of a DPI awareness manager class with a basic usage example with Tkinter:

```
# MIT-0 License
#
# Copyright (c) 2022 Hugo Spinelli
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.

import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
import enum
import itertools
import tkinter


class DPIAware(enum.Enum):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context
    SYSTEM_AWARE = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE(-2)
    PER_MONITOR_AWARE = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE(-3)
    PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE(-4)


class DPIUnaware(enum.Enum):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context
    UNAWARE = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE(-1)
    UNAWARE_GDISCALED = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE(-5)


class ProcessDPIAwareness(enum.Enum):
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness
    UNAWARE = 0
    SYSTEM_AWARE = 1
    PER_MONITOR_AWARE = 2


class DeviceCapsIndex(enum.Enum):
    """Item to be returned by the GetDeviceCaps function."""

    # The values are defined as macros in C, so they are not exposed to the
    # windll API. They can alternatively be obtained from the pywin32 package:
    # pip install pywin32
    # Example:
    #   >>> import win32con
    #   >>> win32con.HORZSIZE
    #   ... 4
    # https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps
    
    HORZSIZE = 4
    """Width, in millimeters, of the physical screen."""
    
    VERTSIZE = 6
    """Height, in millimeters, of the physical screen."""
    
    HORZRES = 8
    """Width, in pixels, of the screen."""
    
    VERTRES = 10
    """Height, in raster lines, of the screen."""
    
    ASPECTX = 40
    """Relative width of a device pixel used for line drawing."""
    
    ASPECTY = 42
    """Relative height of a device pixel used for line drawing."""
    
    ASPECTXY = 44
    """Diagonal width of the device pixel used for line drawing."""
    
    LOGPIXELSX = 88
    """Number of pixels per logical inch along the screen width. In a system
    with multiple display monitors, this value is the same for all monitors."""
    
    LOGPIXELSY = 90
    """Number of pixels per logical inch along the screen height. In a system
    with multiple display monitors, this value is the same for all monitors."""


class DPIManager:
    """DPI awareness manager."""
    
    def __init__(self,
                 aware_state: DPIAware = DPIAware.PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2,
                 unaware_state: DPIUnaware = DPIUnaware.UNAWARE_GDISCALED):
        """Parameters:
        - `aware_state`: Default DPI-aware state. Possible values:
           - `DPIAware.SYSTEM_AWARE`
           - `DPIAware.PER_MONITOR_AWARE`
           - `DPIAware.PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2`
        - `unaware_state`: Default DPI-unaware state. Possible values:
           - `DPIUnaware.UNAWARE`
           - `DPIUnaware.UNAWARE_GDISCALED`
        """
        ctx = ctypes.windll.user32.GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext()
        self._original_awareness = self.get_awareness(ctx)
        self.aware_state = aware_state
        self.unaware_state = unaware_state

    @staticmethod
    def set(awareness: DPIAware | DPIUnaware | ProcessDPIAwareness):
        """Set the DPI awareness state."""
        if awareness in itertools.chain(DPIAware, DPIUnaware):
            ctypes.windll.user32.SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(awareness.value)
        elif awareness in ProcessDPIAwareness:
            # WARNING: This affects all threads in the current process and
            # can only be reversed thread-by-thread
            ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(awareness.value)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid argument type {type(awareness)!r}')

    def toggle(self):
        """Toggle DPI awareness states."""
        if self.is_aware():
            self.set(self.unaware_state)
        else:
            self.set(self.aware_state)

    def restore(self):
        """Restore the original DPI awareness state."""
        self.set(self._original_awareness)

    def is_aware(self, awareness: DPIAware | DPIUnaware | None = None) -> bool:
        """Check if the state is DPI-aware."""
        if awareness is None:
            awareness = self.get_awareness()
        return awareness in DPIAware

    @staticmethod
    def get_awareness(_ctx: int | None = None) -> DPIAware | DPIUnaware:
        """Get the current DPIAwarenessContext parameter."""
        if _ctx is None:
            _ctx = ctypes.windll.user32.GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext()
        for ctx_type in itertools.chain(DPIAware, DPIUnaware):
            if ctypes.windll.user32.AreDpiAwarenessContextsEqual(
                _ctx, ctx_type.value
            ):
                return ctx_type
        raise ValueError(f'Unknown DPI context type ({_ctx!r})')

    @staticmethod
    def get_dpi(_ctx: int | None = None) -> int:
        if _ctx is None:
            _ctx = ctypes.windll.user32.GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext()
        # This might fail and return 0 for PER_MONITOR_AWARE and
        # PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2. This is because the DPI of a per-monitor-aware
        # window can change, and the actual DPI cannot be returned without the
        # window's HWND.
        if dpi := ctypes.windll.user32.GetDpiFromDpiAwarenessContext(_ctx):
            return dpi
        # Set up the DPI awareness context to be checked
        original_ctx = ctypes.windll.user32.GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(_ctx)
        # Create a temporary window to probe the screen DPI
        temp_window = tkinter.Tk()
        dc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(temp_window.winfo_id())
        dpi = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDeviceCaps(
            dc, DeviceCapsIndex.LOGPIXELSX.value
        )
        temp_window.destroy()
        # Restore the original DPI awareness context
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(original_ctx)
        return dpi

    @staticmethod
    def get_scale() -> float:
        """Get the scale factor of the monitor."""
        DEVICE_PRIMARY = 0
        # DEVICE_IMMERSIVE = 1
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-display_device_type
        return ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(DEVICE_PRIMARY)/100


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import tkinter.font
    
    dpi_manager = DPIManager()
    
    def spawn_window(title: str, scale_window: bool = True):
        WIDTH = 260
        HEIGHT = 70

        dpi = dpi_manager.get_dpi()
        awareness = dpi_manager.get_awareness()
        is_aware = dpi_manager.is_aware(awareness)
        scale = dpi_manager.get_scale() if is_aware else 1
        
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title(title)
        width = round(WIDTH*scale) if scale_window else WIDTH
        height = round(HEIGHT*scale) if scale_window else HEIGHT
        root.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')
        font_size = tkinter.font.Font(font='TkDefaultFont').actual()['size']
        label_texts = [
            f'DPI: {dpi}',
            f'Awareness: {awareness.name}',
            f'Font size: {font_size}',
        ]
        canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
        labels = [tkinter.Label(canvas, text=text) for text in label_texts]
        for label in labels:
            label.pack()
        canvas.pack(expand=True)
        tkinter.mainloop()

    # Original state (DPI-unaware)
    spawn_window('1')
    # Toggle state (DPI-aware)
    dpi_manager.toggle()
    # Original settings for the window size
    spawn_window('2', scale_window=False)
    # Properly scaled window
    spawn_window('3', scale_window=True)
    # Restore state (DPI-unaware)
    dpi_manager.toggle()  # or .restore()
    spawn_window('4')
```

On my screen, with 96 DPI and scale factor of 150%, the windows pop up as following:

[image: DPI-Awareness-Tkinter]

Window 2 has the original size (geometry), which looks smaller on a DPI-aware context. Window 3 had its size multiplied by the scale factor to look the same size as window 1. Note that the font size is automatically adjusted by Tkinter. The default size 9 is multiplied by 150% and rounded to 14. I'm not sure if window 4 was supposed to look better than window 1 with the `UNAWARE_GDISCALED` option, but they look the same to me.

Comment: Just a heads-up that I think you might want to **Set** `ctypes.windll.user32.SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(original_ctx)` instead of **Get** at the end of `get_dpi`